# Why is the app crashing when it cannot find the song in the itunes API?

Tags: ios, swift, itunes

I am safely unwrapping, but for some reason the app is still crashing when it cannot find the song equal to the given title. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

```
  let searchTerm: String = playertitle.text!

    let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

    if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let urlPath = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=music"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!



        print("Search iTunes API at URL \(url)")



        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            do {
                if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                {


                    let previewUrl = NSURL(string: (dict["results"]![0]["previewUrl"] as? String)!)!
                    print(previewUrl)
                    player = AVPlayer(URL: previewUrl)




                }

            } catch let jsonError as NSError {

            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guard the response data something like follows,

```
   let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            guard data != nil else {
                print("response String is nil")
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            //completionHandler goes here
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: I found out where the error occurs. It occurs in the `let previewUrl` line. Since the array is empty, there is nothing to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You are safe unwrapping a dictionary and not the results of it. If lets should go one for every possible value. Or take a look at SwiftyJSON framework it allows for lesser if lets.

Answer (score 0):

Don't force unwrap (`!`) `data`! It might be `nil`. Use `if let` or `guard`.

```
if let data = data as? NSData,
  let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

While you're at it, check the `error` parameter too.

When parsing the data, `nil` might be returned everywhere. So be safe here too. Get rid of all force unwraps.

```
if let firstResult = dict["results"]?.first as? NSDictionary,
 let preview = firstResult["previewUrl"] as? String,
 let previewUrl = NSURL(string: preview) {
     ...
 }
```